# How to automatically open a website and perform operations

Tags: c#

I have a website which contains Name, Employee ID, Salary, from and to date. Basically, I used to open that website and enter each value manually.

I would like to automatically open that website and assign values to respected item using C#. NET. I don't know whether it may be possible or not. Can anyone please suggest me the method or an alternative process?

Comment: Look up "web scraping" or "screen scraping".

Comment: I did not get you John, sorry.

Comment: You can use HttpClient to send HTTP requests and receive responses. I suggest using your web browser's debugger to figure out what requests and responses are sent, and imitate them with your client.

Comment: I mean, click "[.net web scraping](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[.net]+web+scraping)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebClient` of `System.Net` namespace to execute a url programatically. The url can contain query strings which can be extracted during loading of the url. The response can then be decoded to string, which essentially will be an html, which you can use as per your convenience.

The following is the method I have to perform the functionality.

```
public static string ReadUrlToString(string url, string method, string postParams, string userName, string password, string domain)
{
    var wc = new WebClient();

    // set the user agent to IE6
    wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

    AssignCredentials(wc, userName, password, domain);

    try
    {
        if (Is.EqualString(method, "POST"))
        {
            // Eg "field1=value1&amp;field2=value2"
            var bret = wc.UploadData(url, "POST", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postParams));

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bret);
        }

        // actually execute the GET request
        return wc.DownloadString(url);
    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {
        // WebException.Status holds useful information
        //throw as needed
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // other errors
        //throw as needed
    }
}
```

The `AssignCredentials` method is as below.

```
private static void AssignCredentials(WebClient wc, string userName, string password, string domain)
{
    if (Is.NotEmptyString(userName))
    {
        wc.Credentials = Is.EmptyString(domain)
                                ? new NetworkCredential(userName, password)
                                : new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.